# passwordless ssh setup without user directory

Tags: ssh, security

Password less SSH without user directory?

The folder `.ssh` should be stored in a user directory as far as I understood.

```
ServerA: Linux without /home/users
ServerB: Linux with /home/users
client:  Linux/mac etc...
```

Cases:

- client password-less ssh to ServerB, no problem
- client password-less ssh to ServerA, no problem
- SeverA password-less ssh to ServerB, **problem!**

If there is no actual user directories in ServerA how public key for each user without user directory existing?

Or is there other ways to safely ssh to ServerB from ServerA?

Comment: At least with OpenSSH, you can set an alternate AuthorizedKeysFile such as /etc/ssh/user/authorized_keys via the sshd_config file. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Do invalid home directory entries exist in the `/etc/passwd` files on ServerA and ServerB?

Comment: This appears to be a client, not server, issue.  More information is needed to accurately solve the problem.  What is the meaning of "SeverA passwordless ssh to ServerB, ***problem***"?  What config did you use, what command did you invoke, and what output do you see?  Have you looked at the output of `ssh -v` or `ssh --trace-ascii` on ServerA or ServerB?

Comment: sorry, Guys, All I know is Server A is centOS, ServerB is an old machine with SGE qsub.

Comment: It is what I expected for my qestions. better close now to avoid wasting everyone 's time. Robert. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is possible to change the authorized keys file location by modifying or adding an entry to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file as such:

`AuthorizedKeysFile /etc/ssh/.authorized_keys`

don't forget to restart sshd after the modification of course

Comment: Since the questioner can log in to A or B with a properly configured client, it appears that the client `ssh` on A and/or B is misconfigured.  Can this answer solve that issue?

Answer (score 1):

`ssh` provides an option `-i` that can point to any file that has the pub key. For example,

```
serverA ~]# ssh -i /path/to/pub/id_rsa username@serverB
```

Comment: I think this might work-around the problem, though doesn't appear to be a solution, because questioner is asking about "ssh setup", implying configuration.  Unfortunately, at this point in time, the question does not provide enough information.

Comment: Yes, the question is two fold. This might answer part of the question where  the use wants to ssh witohut password and wants to store keys in non default location.

Comment: Do you think the question provides sufficient information to solve the problem?

Comment: I would try this tomorrow, my vpn is down today, thanks and sorry for not able to provide enough information